# Algorithm for finding the "visible" part of a three dimesional object

Tags: geometry, algorithms

The objects in question are cuboids. "visible" is defined as a line can be found such that it intersects with a point ("the eye") and the (part of the) object in question, but not any other object.
**What I have so far:**
My original thought was to render/project the entire scene to a plane, and work with the two dimensional shapes instead. However, this doesn't work as I can't "unrender" but I need the three dimensional object.
My second thought was to render/project each obstacle to the planes where the faces of the object lie and "cut" the object. But this quickly gets complicated as there are more and more faces as I cut.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to [occlusion culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occlusion_culling)? Hidden surface removal? One approach not explicitly mentioned at the Wikipedia page is to apply the view projection as a nonlinear transformation in 3D, so that each vertex $(x,y,z)$ is transformed into $(x',y',z')$ in the view frustum, i.e. $(x',y')$ are the "screen" coordinates, and $z'$ is the distance from the view plane.

Comment: For models of $10^6$ atoms and more, I've used a detail map approach. The map size is determined by the desired resolution of details. Each 3D object (facet for multifaceted objects -- I used spheres and right cylinders which kind of have only one surface) is labeled in the map (I added distance from eye to each map element for ease of construction). Each detail map element that has a neighbour with a different object (background or "none" counted as an object) means that area needs to be computed with more precision (but the objects are then already known). It breaks down at the detail size..

Comment: .. as in, objects whose projected size is less than the detail size may or may not vanish, so it's not perfect, but it works really well if you are working with a truly huge number of objects and don't mind the limitation -- or if you can use a detail map with higher resolution than the final image, sufficiently detailed to cover all your visible objects.

Comment: As you can see from the question I am not well versed in mathematics. Please go easy on the bad use of terminology here.

Comment: @NominalAnimal by object I am referring to a mathematical one, as in, one composed of vertices, edges and faces.

Comment: In computer graphics, 3D objects are usually composed of vertices, edges, and faces, and treated as such. (Faces tend to be often limited to triangles, too, although there are techniques for direct rendering of more complex stuff like bicubic patches (curved surfaces) and metaballs.) **Your question is exactly the same as** (early) **computer graphics programmers and mathematicians have wondered at**. Just because the domain feels funny, it is still perfectly applicable, and there has been a LOT of real mathematical research in this arena.

Comment: By *"rectangular prism"*, do you mean [cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid)? (This is a honest question. I just want to understand. I am not a mathematician; I just use math to solve problems. I ask for clarification for the terms because I need to verify if *I* understand your problem correctly. Otherwise my suggestions and possible answer would be misdirected, and possibly worse than useless: misleading. I do not want to mislead.) I tend to call these just "3D boxes".

Comment: @NominalAnimal Yes, by rectangular prism I do mean cuboid.

Comment: Axis-aligned, or in any orientation? Are they all the same size and shape, or of various dimensions?

Comment: @NominalAnimal They are axis-aligned, are all cuboids, but size and dimensions vary.